Retrieve Organization-Wide Email Address Access in Permission set
Salesforce introduced in summer '23 the ability to add permission sets to an organization-wide email address.
But how do I get this setting via sf?
I created a new permission set, selected the org-wide email address, but the resulting permission set xml is empty
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PermissionSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <hasActivationRequired>false</hasActivationRequired>
    <label>test</label>
</PermissionSet>

in what metadata type is it stored?
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_productivity_email_owea_permission_sets.htm&release=244&type=5
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfDdUAJ/orgwide-emails-addresses-in-permission-sets

org-wide email addresses are not supported as metadata: 
I believe that is why you don't see it. You would need to manually add it to the permission set in each environment (org).
